# Dojo FilteringSelect SearchAttr search name of attribute of array

Tags: arrays, filter, dojo, dojox.mobile

I have the following array:

```
    [{"id":1,"vak":{"naam":"Wiskunde"},"onderwerp":"Dit is het onderwerp van de les ..."},
     {"id":2,"vak":{"naam":"Aardrijkskunde"},"onderwerp":"Bli Bla, Dit is het onderwerp van de les ..."},
     {"id":3,"vak":{"naam":"Biologie"},"onderwerp":"Dit is het onderwerp van de les ..."},
     {"id":4,"vak":{"naam":"Wizkunde"},"onderwerp":"Dit is het onderwerp van de les ..."}]
```

I want to implement a filteringSelect that searches for "naam".
When I search for "onderwerp", I just set my searchAttr like this:

```
    this.lessonsSearchBox.set("searchAttr", "onderwerp");
```

But I don't know how to set my searchAttr if I want to search for "naam", because "naam" is an attribute from "vak".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (and looked at the source code), you can't. It's just using that attribute as the property name.

The best solution I can come up with is by mapping your array, for example by doing the following:

```js
var newRoosterItems = array.map(roosterItems, function(item) {
    var newItem = lang.clone(item);
    lang.mixin(newItem, {
        vakNaam: item.vak.naam
    });
    return newItem;
});
```

This maps your array to a new array of items and every item will have a property called `vakNaam` which contains the `naam` property of your `vak`.

An example JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/jbfjL/).

---

If you don't need the original data, you can also choose to convert the existing data, by using:

```js
array.forEach(roosterItems, function(item) {
    lang.mixin(item, {
        vakNaam: item.vak.naam
    });
});
```